# Pseudo-Anosov map with n-prong singularity

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

Whether the following statemant is correct (I guess the answer is "Yes" and I guess that maybe it is trivial for an expert about Pseudo-Anosov map)?

"For a given $n\in N$, there exists a closed orientbale surface $\Sigma^n$ such that there exists a pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphism 
$f_n$ on $\Sigma^n$ with an $n$-prong singularity. "

Could you pleae provide me some references or comments?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes and essentially the only restriction on the singularity type (=number of prongs) is the one coming from Euler-Poincare formula. For further details, I think an useful reference is, e.g., the book "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups" by B. Farb and D. Margalit (http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9495.html).

Comment: The result to which Matheus is referring is a theorem in the paper by Masur and Smillie entitled "Quadratic differentials with prescribed singularities and pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphisms", MR1214233.

Comment: @Matheus and @Lee, thank you very much. Your answers are exactly what I need.  